# difference in results of hypothesis when checking with histogram and boxplot

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, inference, descriptive-statistics

[image]I'm not sure why results differ when I'm doing hypothesis with wilcox test for data, the hypothesis results differ from normal boxplot and histogram. Which is the best graph to check the results for the hypothesis if its correct.

whereas hypothesis is rejecting null; which is men and female are equal

First graph says: Men and female has difference

second graph says : men and female are equal

[image]

Comment: I don't understand how you infer from the histograms that there is a difference in location.

Comment: by simplying looking at the graph im assuming that they both are different, I'm just trying to understand how to infer the hypothesis. Also, not sure how to understand why in these both graphs are difference. can you tell me ?

Comment: I don't see a location difference in the histograms. You are not interpreting the plot correctly.

Comment: @Roland are you saying my results should match with histogram? and cos boxplot clearly shows male and female are equal, and histogram says"orange" is more then "purple" which is female and male. I'm not quit understand why, the way I'm looking in histogram is not location I'm looking overall which entry is more and comparing with the hypothesis, maybe I'm interpreting wrong.

Comment: No, the histogram does not say '"orange" is more then "purple"', not at all. You need to study how to interpret a histogram. You have more orange observations than purple observations but that corresponds to sample sizes. The values, for which you want to compare the location statistics, are on the y-axis.

Comment: @Roland if i check the location statistics, can you tell me from which point it say they are equal according to test? If i look at y axis which is 3 median, it still doesn't say they are equal

Comment: I don't get your issue, The median of the orange histogram is 3. The median of the purple histogram is also 3. 3 equals 3.

Comment: @Roland thankyou for the answers, i personally feel i should understand the graphs better, i was actually looking at the size of the graphs that one is small and other is bigger, that's why! would you suggest any resource for graph reading?